# Real time accounting changes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, web-applications

I'm trying to have a label which contains a balance change when a person enters a charge amount. So assume something like...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="remainingBudget"></td>
        .
        .
        .
```

...and then....

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="percentCommitment"></td>
            <td><input class="totalAmount"></td>
            .
            . 
            .
```

The user will never touch the `totalAmount` form input, only `percentCommitment`, which will calculate `totalAmount` based on another value, which we don't need to worry about. I have the totalAmount input populating automatically on the keydown event of percentCommitment with something like this...

```
$(".percentCommitment").keyup(function() {
    var commit = caluculatePercentCommitment() || 0;
    var salary = getSalary();
    var amount;
    if (commit > 0 && salary > 0) {
        ttl = (salary * commit) / 100;
    } else {
        amount = 0.00;
    }

    $(this).parent().find('.amountCommitment').val(amount);
});
```

This part is working fine and the total amount calculates correctly in real time as the person changes the `percentCommitment` value. This works because the value I multiply the percent commitment by, the person's annual salary, is static. It doesn't change. So if the person enters 1, 1% of salary is calculated and displayed. If the user then tacks on a 2, 12% is calculated from the same original salary, and this is exactly what I want to happen.

The problem comes with calculating the remaining budget in real time. Subtracting `totalAmount` from `remainingBudget` poses a problem, because if the user does the same thing, enters 1, then my jQuery does `newRemainingBudget = remainingBudget - (0.01 * salary)`, which is fine, but then if they tack on a 2 I'm doing `newNewRemainingBudget = newRemainingBudget - (0.12 * salary)`, which isn't what I want. I want all changes to be computed from the *original* remaining budget.

I was trying to do something like this...

```
 $(".totalAmount").change(function (event) {
            var remain = $(".remainingBudget").text();
            remain = formatDecimalInput(remain);
            var enter = $(".totalAmount).val();
            enter = formatDecimalInput(enter);
            if (enter <= remain) {
                $(".remainingBudget")text((remain-enter).formatCurrency());
            }
            else {
                // Do nothing
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a place on the screen that holds the total budget amount and calculate remaining amount using it plus the other fields. Don't use a field in this way when you are replacing.

```
remainingBudget = totalBudget - (0.01 * salary)
```

Note: You can have a hidden form field to hold the total if you want.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking, hidden field...Thanks Lee.